# Cell color change if no formula or manually overwritten

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

Is it possible to change a cell color in excel if that cell doesn't contains a formula anymore or if it is manually overwritten and loses its formula?

Comment: If you have the ISFORMULA function you could use conditional formatting - `=NOT(ISFORMULA(A7))`

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to change attributes of a cell (like color, font etc.) without modifying the cell's value or formula. One way is to use conditional formatting as suggested in the comment section. If you want to use vba, the code to modify the background color of cells is

```
Range("A1").Interior.ColorIndex = colorCode 'You can replace range also by other range-objects like  cells(1, 1)
```

You can find the colorCode for your specific color and more information about this formula here: [ColorIndex property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.colorindex)

What you want is to iterate through all cells and check whether the cell has a formula or not.

```
for i = 1 to x 'replace x by the number of rows you have
   if (cells(i, y).isformula = false) then 'replace y by the column you want to search
      cells(i, y).Interior.ColorIndex
   End If
Next
```